# Norm of a sequence of functionals detail, Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

> I am reading the following theorem  from  this [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2044800?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
>
> [image]

I'm stuck in the part "Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that ... " ( I can't see why this sequence exist), from [6] I can follow the existence of the $x_{n}^{*}$  such that $\left\Vert x_{n}^{*}\right\Vert =1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but why $\left\langle x_{n},x_{n}^{*}\right\rangle =1$ ? doesn't  this  mean that  $x_{n}^{*}$ attains its maximum in $x_n$ ? Why is this possible?   Am I missing something?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $$1= ||x^*_n|| = \sup \{|\langle x, x_n^* \rangle|; x \in B_X\},$$
where $B_X$ is the closed unit ball of $X$. Hence there is some $y \in B_X$ such that $|\langle y,x_n^* \rangle| > 1/2$. Take a complex unit $\alpha$, such that $$|\langle y,x_n^* \rangle| = \alpha \langle y, x_n^* \rangle = \langle \alpha y,x_n^* \rangle.$$
Then $\alpha y \in B_X$ and $\langle \alpha y,x_n^* \rangle > 1/2$. Now just take $x_n = \frac{\alpha y}{\langle \alpha y,x_n^* \rangle}$. Then
$$||x_n|| \leq 2 ||\alpha y|| \leq 2.$$
Also
$$\langle x_n,x_n^* \rangle = \frac{\langle \alpha y,x_n^* \rangle}{\langle \alpha y,x_n^* \rangle}=1.$$
The important thing is that you require $x_n$ to be in $2B_X$ instead of $B_X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This makes perfect sense.